# How to get dropdown widget output as a dataframe?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

Here is the code to filter a dataframe based on field and wellname using two dropdowns. The filter is applied to pandas dataframe and I want filtered output (common_filter) also to be a type of pandas dataframe. Currently, when the is of widgets type. Is there any way of getting it as dataframe?

The code below is taken from TowardsDataScience and modified a bit.

"unique_sorted_values" function simply returns a list of unique sorted values of passed array, in this case FieldID and WellnameID

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'FieldID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                        'WellnameID':['1_A', '1_A', '2_A', '1_B', '1_B', '2_B', '2_B'],
                        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

output = widgets.Output()

dropdown_field = widgets.Dropdown(options = unique_sorted_values(df.FieldID))
dropdown_wellname = widgets.Dropdown(options = unique_sorted_values(df[df.FieldID==dropdown_field.value].WellnameID))

def common_filtering(field, wellname):
    output.clear_output()

    common_filter = df[(df.FieldID == field) & (df.WellnameID == wellname)]

    with output:
        display(common_filter)

def dropdown_field_eventhandler(change):
    common_filtering(change.new, dropdown_wellname.value)
def dropdown_wellname_eventhandler(change):
    common_filtering(dropdown_field.value, change.new)

dropdown_field.observe(dropdown_field_eventhandler, names='value')
dropdown_wellname.observe(dropdown_wellname_eventhandler, names='value')

input_widgets = widgets.HBox([dropdown_field, dropdown_wellname])
display(input_widgets)

display(output)
```

Comment: Please can you provide a MCVE? Create a mock version of your input dataframe with the FieldID and WellnameID populated with some dummy values. When you ask for 'filtered output', are you asking to get the `common_filter` dataframe object returned from the function?

Comment: Edited by adding dummy data. Yes, I mean getting `common_filter` dataframe object returned each time after updating the dropdown widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the `return` value of the function for the dataframe as the return value is not assigned to anything in the main body of the code (it is passed to the interact as a callback). As you want to create a whole new dataframe (rather than modify an existing one), a simple way would be to use the `global` keyword on a copied version of the initial data.

After choosing the dropdowns, you should be able to get the `filtered` dataframe in a cell below and see the impact of the filters. If you need anything more complex, you probably want to construct a `class` object to track the state of data, apply filters etc.

```py
    import ipywidgets as widgets
    import pandas as pd

    # dummy data
    df = pd.DataFrame({'FieldID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                            'WellnameID':['1_A', '1_A', '2_A', '1_B', '1_B', '2_B', '2_B'],
                            'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

    filtered = pd.DataFrame()
    output = widgets.Output()

    dropdown_field = widgets.Dropdown(options = sorted(df.FieldID.unique()))
    dropdown_wellname = widgets.Dropdown(options = sorted(df[df.FieldID==dropdown_field.value].WellnameID.unique()))

    def common_filtering(field, wellname):
        global filtered
        output.clear_output()

        filtered = df[(df.FieldID == field) & (df.WellnameID == wellname)]

        with output:
            display(filtered)

    def dropdown_field_eventhandler(change):
        common_filtering(change.new, dropdown_wellname.value)
    def dropdown_wellname_eventhandler(change):
        common_filtering(dropdown_field.value, change.new)

    dropdown_field.observe(dropdown_field_eventhandler, names='value')
    dropdown_wellname.observe(dropdown_wellname_eventhandler, names='value')

    input_widgets = widgets.HBox([dropdown_field, dropdown_wellname])
    display(input_widgets)

    display(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is is possible to initially (first output) show all the values and then filter based on the selection?